# Set loading bitmap to spinner in progress dialog

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I used a tutorial that showed me how to load bitmaps in an async task and set them to an imageview and in the tutorial before the bitmap is loaded the imageview is set to black with this piece of code

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
private final WeakReference<DownloadImageTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

public DownloadedDrawable(DownloadImageTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
    super(Color.BLACK);
    bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
        new WeakReference<DownloadImageTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
}

public DownloadImageTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
    return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
}
}
```

How can I change the imageview so that before it is loaded it is the spinner in the progress dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try aquery android library for lazy loading image and listview...below code may help you.....

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(mContext);
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://data.whicdn.com/images/63995806/original.jpg");
```

You can download library from [from this link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar)